# NodeMCU resest with mqtt.client:close()), or mqtt.client:connect()

Tags: lua, mqtt, nodemcu

I have an application that uses mqtt for communication between modules and with a mobile terminal.

In some situations when the messages do not arrive, the node performs a self test of MQTT (sending a msg to itself), and when the selftest fails, tries to reconnect to the broker (mqtt offline not always arrives). And then two problems may arise:
If I perform a mqtt.client:close() to assure that the client is closed (to avoid the second problem) and the client is already closed, the node resets.
If I perform a mqtt.client:connect() and the client is still connected, an exception and a restet occurs.

is there a way to know if the mqtt client is connected or not?

Thanks for your comment. I am going to describe what I am doing, to see if you can help me:
I have two independent system, a master and a slave. The master publish a test message every 10 minutes. If there is no answer from the slave. it publish a test message to itself. If this self test does not arrive, a disconnection from the broker is assumed, and a reconnection is initiated.

And here is where the problem comes, sometimes the client is disconnected and everything go well, but sometimes it is still connected but unresponsive, and the node resets with an exception "already connected".

Performing a mqtt:close() previously to the reconnection, should be safe, but if I send it and the client is truly disconnected, the node resets without any reason (known to me).

All this is happening without receiving any offline message.

Comment: Thanks, your edits helped shorten my answer. The recommendations remain the same - use events and function outputs based on the client's internal state, rather than listening for messages from the master.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for messages manually sent by the master client (which could fail to send for various reasons, leading a listening device to the wrong conclusion about the state of its connection to the broker), I recommend using MQTT's built-in connection management.

- First, you can make sure that each client's initial connection has succeeded by including an [error handler in `:connect()`](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/mqtt/#notes_1). If the client really opens, nothing in the NodeMCU documentation indicates that it will close itself; it may go `offline`.
- Once connected, the client only knows that something is wrong when it sends a message and does not receive a response. It sounds like you are not calling `:publish()` much (which would otherwise let you know by returning false), so pinging may be best. If you expect to receive a message from the broker every n seconds, set a keepalive time slightly higher than that on the client.
- Then, failure to get a response to those messages should [trigger an event](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/mqtt/#mqttclienton) that you can respond to. That might be something like the following (not tested, may work better called outside the callback):
  `m:on("offline", function(client) m:close() end)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've included a better description in the original post.